# Facebook Authorization Pop-up Window Doesn't Auto Close

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am using the following code from [**think different tutorial**](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/) and implemented it successfully, The only problem is that the authentication pop up window doesn't closes automatically after successfull user login.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var button;
    var userInfo;

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({ appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true});

        function updateButton(response) {
            button =   document.getElementById('fb-auth');
            userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');

            if (response.authResponse) {
                //user is already logged in and connected
                FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                login(response, info);
                });

                button.onclick = function() {
                FB.logout(function(response) {
                logout(response);
                });
                };
            } else {
                //user is not connected to your app or logged out
                button.innerHTML = 'Login';
                button.onclick = function() {
                    showLoader(true);
                        FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                            login(response, info);
                            });
                        } else {
                            //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                        }
                    }, {scope:'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_about_me'});
                }
            }
        }

        // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
        FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol
        + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());

    function login(response, info){
    if (response.authResponse) {
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

    userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + info.id + '/picture">' + info.name + "<br /> Your Access Token: " + accessToken;
    button.innerHTML = 'Logout';
    document.getElementById('other').style.display = "block";
    }
    }

    function logout(response){
    userInfo.innerHTML  = "";
    document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('other').style.display = "none";
    }
    }

</script>
<body>
<button id="fb-auth">Login</button>
```

Comment: what web browser are you using? have you tested it in several?

Comment: works on all browsers except opera

Comment: Yes but why Opera,although I can ignore it but there must be a reason ...

Comment: do you have adblock installed?

Comment: No ad block and not even PC security suite installed just a fresh install of windows and opera